# To get count of duplicate column values

Tags: android

I have created a table with id and tag as column.

id is set as primary key. And in tag column, I have entered more than one value.

So now i want to get the count of how many times the tag value is repeated.

So my table is like this.

```
Id    Tag
---------------------
1     Friend, Family
2     Family, Enemy
```

and my output should be like this:

```
friend (1)
family(2)
Enemy(1)
```

I have written a code but not getting the result I want.

This is `MyDatabase.java` code:

```
public Details calculateCount()
{
    Details detail = null;

    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

         String selectQuery=("select count(*),Tags from photodetails group by Tags" );

          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToLast())
        {
            do
            {

             detail=new Details(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),(cursor.getString(1)));


            }while( cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return detail;
}
```

And this is MAinActivity.java code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

          MyDataBase MyDB  = new MyDataBase(this);
  Log.d(LOGCAT,"Entered MAinActivity2");

Details c= MyDB.calculateCount();


 if(c == null)
 {
     Log.d(LOGCAT,"C is null");

 }
 else
 {
 Log.d(LOGCAT,c.getTag()); // Here iam only retrieving tag dont know how to get that count.
 }

  }
```

Pls help me out on this

Comment: What are you getting with your current code? What does your log say?

Comment: in my log iam geting the the first two tags only ie friend and family

Comment: I'm a little confused, what's the column name for "Family" and "Enemy" then? Or is the entire "Friend, Family" and "Family, Enemy" the value in column `Tag` ?

Comment: ya the coloumn name is Tag. friend family enemy are values in the coloumn

Comment: @erad (why people do so?!) he put **2 values** in the same column!!

Comment: ya i want to have 2 values in same coloumn. Is it wrong???

Comment: Yea I'm gonna go with @FrankN.Stein here and tell you , first of all, you probably don't want to be putting two values in the same entry. You're probably going to want to put it in two different rows. That being said, it can technically be done.

Comment: `it can technically be done.` but it would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: ok i will try to add one value

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I totally agree with you. But I had a case where I was writing a library app and the client already had the data in a fat string like `fiction, young adult, hardcover` and rather than create three rows for the same book, I did just put all that stuff into one column and wrote a method to parse that data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a count, you're going to want to create a method such as a `int getCount()` method that will return the int value of the count. Currently, you have `Details calculateCount()` which will return a Details object.

Comment: but then only count can be displayed. I want to display the tag value also thats why i thought of Details Calculatecount()

Comment: Oh. In that case, your question is a little misleading. You said "i want to get the count of how many times the tag value is repeated." What do you REALLY want? You want to simply display the tag values?

Comment: i have written the kind of output i need

Comment: You better follow the normalization rule: "1 field, 1 value"

Comment: Well without knowing what your `Details` object looks like, why don't you use something like `c.getCount()` ? (or whatever the method is to get that Integer in `Details(Integer, String)`)

Comment: k now i have changed the table and it has got onevalue in each coloumn. But then also iam not getting the count. And in log only one tag value is shown

Comment: Also, I agree with @FrankN.Stein again. The way you're doing it right now, you would get a count=1 for two objects, since the SQL query is looking for the entire value and the only two values "Friend, Family" and "Family, Enemy" are unique. As one value, the SQL query will not know that those are actually two tags.

Comment: `select count(Tags),Tags 
from photodetails 
group by Tags`

Comment: And your `Details calculateCount()` method is overwriting `detail` each time, so obviously you're not going to be returning more than one Detail. Your line `Details c= MyDB.calculateCount();` will only put ONE `Details` object into variable `c`. Thus, your log will only show that one object.